# Create a loop to subsets a Dataframe based a boolean value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, subset, slice

I have a problem coding a loop to subset a Dataframe in Python.

This is my first post on stack overflow and I have started to code fews months ago so I am sorry if I am doing something wrong ..! I have looked over the web for days now but couldn't find an answer (my keywords might have been poorly chosen..)

To give some context, here is how I obtained my df from a csv file:

```
#Library

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Assisgn spreadsheets filenames and read files into a Dataframe

file_20 = '/Users/cortana/Desktop/Projet stage/DAT/dat_clean/donnees_assemblees_20.csv'
df_20_initial = pd.read_csv(file_20, sep=';', usecols=[0, 2, 3])

#Create dictionary with tables names as keys

tables_names_20 = pd.DataFrame.dropna(df_20_initial.iloc[:,[0]])
tables_names_20 = tables_names_20.set_index('20').T.to_dict()

#Slice the global dataframe and store the subsets into the dictionary as values

df_20_initial['separators'] = df_20_initial['time'].isna() #add a new column that check for missing values (separators)

print(df_20_initial)
```

Here is what my df looks like:

```
       20      time  velocity  separators
0    P1S1  6.158655  0.136731       False
1     NaN  6.179028  0.244889       False
2     NaN  6.199253  0.386443       False
3     NaN  6.219323  0.571861       False
4     NaN  6.239505  0.777680       False
..    ...       ...       ...         ...
520   NaN  7.008377  1.423408       False
521   NaN  7.028759  1.180113       False
522   NaN  7.048932  0.929300       False
523   NaN  7.068993  0.673909       False
524   NaN  7.089557  0.413527       False

[525 rows x 4 columns]
```

Based on the boolean value present in the "separators" column, I would like to create a new Dataframe containing the values of the "time" and "velocity" column, sliced when the "separators" value is True.

To do so, I have unsuccessfully tried to code the following loop:

```
for lab, row in df_20_initial.iterrows() :
    if df_20_initial.iloc[:,3] == False :
        P1S1 = df_20_intermediate[['time', 'velocity']]
    else :
      break
```

... and got this error message from Python:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any advices is welcome, and thank you all in advance for your time!

Comment: Do you want to get a list of "partial DataFrames", i.e. to split it into chunks?

Comment: Yes I would like to have separated dataframes insted of the big table I have now (525 rows x 4 columns). They should be 10 tables, but they do not contain the same amount of rows. So thats why I would like to create a loop that discriminate the tables based on the 'separators' column, to slice the global df into chunks when the value is 'True'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my experiments I used your DataFrame with *separators* set to *True*
in some rows:

```
     20      time  velocity  separators
0  P1S1  6.158655  0.136731       False
1   NaN  6.179028  0.244889       False
2   NaN  6.199253  0.386443       False
3   NaN  6.219323  0.571861        True
4   NaN  6.239505  0.777680       False
5   NaN  7.008377  1.423408       False
6   NaN  7.028759  1.180113       False
7   NaN  7.048932  0.929300        True
8   NaN  7.068993  0.673909       False
9   NaN  7.089557  0.413527       False
```

I assumed that *separators* column is of *bool* type.

To generate a list of chunks you can use e.g. the following list
comprehension:

```
dfList = [ chunk[['time', 'velocity']] for _, chunk in
    df_20_initial.groupby(df_20_initial.separators.cumsum()) ]
```

Now when you e.g. print *dfList[1]* you will get:

```
       time  velocity
3  6.219323  0.571861
4  6.239505  0.777680
5  7.008377  1.423408
6  7.028759  1.180113
```

But if you want to drop separator rows, run:

```
dfList2 = [ chunk[~chunk.separators][['time', 'velocity']] for _, chunk in
    df_20_initial.groupby(df_20_initial.separators.cumsum()) ]
```

(from each chunk leave only rows with *separators == False*).

Comment: Is it possible to reset the index (starting back to 0) for each chunks?

Comment: It is possible. After *chunk[['time', 'velocity']]* add *.reset_index(drop=True)*.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is really good at Boolean slices. If I understand your question correctly, I think all you need is:

`new_df = df_20_initial[df_20_initial['separators']]`

If you want to remove the 'separators' column from the output, you can just select the remaining columns like so:

`new_df = df_20_initial[df_20_initial['separators']][['time', 'velocity']]`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer! Unfortunately when I run the code with your solution the values in the 'time' and 'velocity' columns turns into NaN and I don't get separated dataframes based on the 'True' value of the column 'separators'.